# Multithreading code returns different results from iterative one

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

The `Assert.assertArrayEquals` fails because of different elements in position `45965` and this means that the last `byte` for the first thread is wrong (but it's still written somehow) and I don't understand why.

Here's the code:

```
int repetitions = 3;
byte[] inputByte = new byte[183860];
int numThreads = 4;
int minItemsPerThread = inputByte.length / numThreads;
int maxItemsPerThread = minItemsPerThread + 1;
int threadsWithMaxItems = inputByte.length - numThreads * minItemsPerThread;
int start = 0;
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numThreads);
final byte[] threadResult = new byte[inputByte.length * repetitions];

for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    int itemsCount = (i < threadsWithMaxItems ? maxItemsPerThread : minItemsPerThread);
    int end = start + itemsCount;
    final byte[] array = Arrays.copyOfRange(inputByte, start, end);
    final int fStart = start;
    // Thread
    executor.submit(() -> {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(array);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(array.length * repetitions);
        // Processing
        myObject.process(bis, bos);
        byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
        // Write in final result array
        System.arraycopy(result, 0, threadResult, fStart, itemsCount);
        latch.countDown();
    });

    start = end;
}

latch.await();

// Stream setup
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputByte);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// Processing
myObject.process(bis, bos);
outputByte = bos.toByteArray();

Assert.assertArrayEquals(outputByte, threadResult);
```

Comment: because concurrent execution is non-deterministic

Comment: I understand that the question may not be clear enough, but the result here does not depend from the order of execution. Each subarray is independent and the each thread has its own indexes defined in the sequential part. Thread 1 always works on (0,45965), thread 2 on (45966, 91931) and so on.

Comment: The problem here is not the concurrent execution. The size of `result` is `itemsCount` * `repetitions`. However you only copy `itemsCount` elements into `threadResult`. But in the end `assertArrayEquals` fails because   `threadResult` is three times larger than `outputByte`. btw. You should always post runnable code so people can test it themselves.

Comment: @SpiderPig Oh well, it really slipped from my mind. The correct version is `System.arraycopy(result, 0, threadResult, fStart*repetitions, itemsCount*repetitions)`, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it. @JarrodRoberson as you can see concurrency was not the problem, you can lift your downvote now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not the concurrent execution. The size of `result` is `itemsCount` * `repetitions`. However you only copy `itemsCount` elements into `threadResult`. But in the end `assertArrayEquals` fails because `threadResult` is three times larger than `outputByte`. btw. You should always post runnable code so people can test it themselves.